# New list<string> not acting indepently

Tags: c#, list

I have `List<string>` I am passing from model to control and back again.  My initial problem was that when I use `List.remove()` to remove an item from the `list<>` it is somehow coming back when passing it back to the View.

I decided to create a new `list<>`, put the `model.List<>` values in it, clear the `Model.List<>`, and then put the values from the tmp `List<>` back in the `Model.List<>`.

However, when I clear the `Model.List<>` the tmp `List<>` values are being cleared as well.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.removeDate))
{
   model.multipleSingleDay_Date.Remove(model.removeDate);                
   List<string> tmpV = new List<string>();
   tmpV = model.multipleSingleDay_Date;
   model.multipleSingleDay_Date.Clear();
   model.multipleSingleDay_Date = tmpV;         
}
```

Comment: Well, you're just grabbing a reference to `model.multipleSingleDay_Date`, not copying it to a new list.

Comment: Just to clarify what other pointed out, When you do this `tmpV = model.multipleSingleDay_Date;` you are making tmpV point to the same object of model.multipleSingleDay_Date.

Comment: You are assigning a `new List<string>()` to that tmpV variable, but in the next line you *overwrite* that with the `model.multipleSingleDay_Date`

Comment: To copy a List use var list2 = list1.ToList();

Comment: It dosn't seem like you need to copy the list - you just need to remove an item from the initial list. I'd figure out _why_ that's not working before coming up with come convoluted copy routine that creates other problems.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a reference to the original list.

To make a new list, use a `new List<string>();` and iterate through your original list to fill the new one. This can be done in several ways.

```
tmpV = model.multipleSingleDay_Date;
```

All the above line does is say "*the reference the variable* `model.multipleSingleDay_Date` *has should be used in the tmpV variable*".

Loop through the original list and add each value to the new list. Or copy the list, see comments below.

Comment: `var tmpV = model.multipleSingleDay_Date.ToList();` would be an easy way to make a copy of the list.